# Could not initialize class util.HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

I'm getting this error when I try to run my WS
Couldn't find any solutions, if anyone could help me

Running Hibernate 4.3 on Netbeans

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendas?useTimeZone=true;useSSL=false;serverTimezone=UTC;autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <mapping class="entity.Cliente"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**ClienController.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package api;

import entity.Cliente;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import util.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author lucas
 */
@Path("clientes")
public class ClientController {
    
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
    
    public ClientController() {
        
    }
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getTeste() {
        
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        
        Query select = session.createQuery("from Cliente");
        List<Cliente> objetos = select.list();
        
        objetos.forEach(item -> {
           System.out.println("name: " + item.getNomeCliente()); 
        });
        
        return "";
    }
}
```

Maybe some missing jar on server?
Running on GlassFish 4.1.1

Server returns the message

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class util.HibernateUtil
```

Please help me to sort out this issue thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to import util.HibernateUtil. You may need to either declare the HibernateUtil class as static eg `public static class HibernateUtils{` and then using by writing `HibernateUtil.doAThing();` or instantiate a HibernateUtil Object eg `HibernateUtil hibUtil = new HibernateUtil();` and use `hibUtil.doAThing();` instead.For the latter though you'll need to include a Constructor to your HibernateUtil class.